# Автоматический вход в систему по ссылке

Tags: lsfusion

Потребовалось открывать программу под определенным пользователем с определенными правами с планшета.
Нужно чтобы открывалась определенная панель просто нажимая на ссылку на рабочем столе.
как выбрать форму по умолчанию при входе пользователя - нашел в администрировании.

Вопрос: Можно ли указать имя и пароль пользователя прямо в ссылке на открытие веб страницы или какой-то другой, допустим, временный идентификатор?

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно.

В четвертой версии платформы добавлена поддержка аутентификации пользователя непосредственно в url при помощи параметров user и password (например http://myserver?user=X&password=Y).

Подробнее про аутентификацию можно почитать в статье на Хабре:
https://habr.com/ru/company/lsfusion/blog/534756/